# How to register a custom exception mapper in Mule + Jersey + Spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, jersey, mule

I built a exception mapper using JAX-RS ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class MyCustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException>{...}
```

It is unclear to me is how to register it so that when MyException is thrown, the mapper is called automatically.  The environment I am using is Mule + Jersey + Spring.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 3.1.2-SNAPSHOT+ or 3.2-SNAPSHOT+ you can do this:

```
<jersey:resources>
    <component class="org.mule.module.jersey.HelloWorldResource"/>
    <jersey:exception-mapper class="org.mule.module.jersey.exception.HelloWorldExceptionMapper" />
</jersey:resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

This response says to use @Repository with Spring

[JAX-RS Custom ExceptionMapper not intercept RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775132/jax-rs-custom-exceptionmapper-not-intercept-runtimeexception/5775363#5775363)

Answer (score 2):

Mule 3.4.0 includes the support:

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5458

```
<sub-flow name="RestServiceFlow">
    <jersey:resources>
        <component class="org.example.AResource"/>
        <component class="org.example.BResource"/>
        <jersey:exception-mapper class="org.example.AExceptionHandler" />
        <jersey:exception-mapper class="org.example.BExceptionHandler" />
    </jersey:resources>
</sub-flow>
```

The classes are annotated with the @Provider annotation as described in the question.